# How to add the most top & bottom row on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge the first and the last row using the =cell1&cell2 function of the table but was unable to as the number of row can be dynamic.

Tried using the relative distance using ctrl+up but to no avail.

Ideally a VBA code where I can use the "&" function to merge the most top and last row of the table then paste special on top as text

```
Sub Macro9()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-9]C&R[-2]C"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to know the relative distance? So you want to count how many rows there are in your table? Or you want the top value and last value combined? And are we actually speaking about a table as in a list object? If so, are there headers to consider?

Comment: To clarify, what I need is that say I have Row 1 (the first row) and Row 12 (as the last row), on Row 14 - it should look like "=Row 1&Row 12"

Comment: And what is it you have done so far? Where is your code? What part is not working?

Comment: Edited and added the attempted macro

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , what you want is a way to address the last cell in a column.

You can do this as follows:

```
Set sht = Sheets("main")
column = 1
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).Row
Set lastCell = sht.Cells(lastRow, column)
```

`lastCell` is a range variable referencing the last cell in the column specified by the `column` variable. I explicitly referenced the sheet to avoid problems with active sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MergeCells()
    col = 1    // column A
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Mcell = Cells(1, col) & Cells(lastRow, col)
End Sub
```